# What is the diffrance in bit frequency and sybmol frequency in manchster coding?

Tags: frequency

I want to know about difference in symbol frequency and bit frequency. i.e if I want to send data with 100 bits per second what will be the carrier frequency for manchester coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

There are twice as many edge transitions in manchester encoding because the clock is exclusive ORed with the data.

This means there are potentially twice as many symbols as data bits.

> what will be the carrier frequency for manchester code

The "carrier frequency" will be a clock that is synchronous with the data as per the above diagram.